# Replacing certain text on a page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, text, replace

I have an issue with a CMS I'm  using where I can't insert a product CMS page with symbols like Registered Trademark (R) and copying right (C) etc. (very annoying) so I need a work around.

Im trying to work out the code for replacing a text string (r) with the actual symbol '®'.

Ive come close, the page loads, and the text string is changed to the symbol  but it seems to get caught in an infinite loop. How do i get this to stop?

Also, there is a delay from when the page loads to when the string changes to the symbol - am I able to stop this or at lease shorten it? Note: The delay only occurs when I run it in the CMS. There doesn't seem to be one when I do test page with just the below code in it.

```js
var replaced = $("body").html().replace('(r)','&reg;');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Hello, this is a test replacing(r).</h3>
<h4>Hello, this is a test replacing(r).</h4>
<p>Hello, this is a test replacing(r).</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do html entities work? `&copy;` or `&reg;` you really shouldn't need to replace entities on the client side. In some languages/CMS/frameworks you can buffer the output or intercept the output and then do the replace on the server side.

If you have to do it on the client side doing something like

```
var content = $("body").html();
content = content.split('(r)').join('&reg;');
content = content.split('(c)').join('&copy;');
$("body").html(content);
```

You could neaten this up using an object (map) to store the replacements then iterating over it. The flash is fairly inevitable unless you hide the content until the replacement is done which is likely even more undesirable.

Comment: Typo in my text - I meant to say product CSV (not CMS) file. This is where the problem is - the html symbols work in the CMS but they won't import from the CSV so every time the products are exported, edited and then imported again (using the CSV file) the symbols are replaced with '?'. This is why I need to add a jQuery hack on the client side.

Comment: good answer +1 for u, even though the question is all over the place ... :)

Comment: Ah OK that makes much more sense however if importing/exporting them can you do the replaces during the import/export process? Usually for problems like this it's best to only use client side hacks as an absolute last resort. The only other thought I've got is why can't the CSV handle the html entities I'd guess the semi-colon? I wonder if it's more just a matter of escaping the problem character(s) which would fix the issue for all html entities not just specific ones